# How do I remove the Previous and Next links?

Tags: javascript

The Previous and Next button links are causing accessibility errors and I would like to remove them (don't really need them for what I am using them anyway).

Is there a way to do this?

The error message is the following one:

> This button element does not have a name available to an accessibility API. Valid names are: title attribute, element content.

I have managed to hide the links from being displayed, but the error messages are still there. All I managed to do is get the css to set the display to none. Is there a way to completely remove the links from the code?

Comment: What module added them in the first place? Without that info, your question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

On the MANAGE DISPLAY of the content type that has this image edit the formatter for the colorbox image. There set the **Gallery (image grouping) > No Gallery**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that @TheodorosPloumis

The only thing is I don't have a formatter for the colorbox image. I am using Views to display the images by calling the colorbox trigger... Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: I also forgot to mention that my colorbox displays the body of the node.

Comment: Unticking the Automatic generated Colorbox gallery option on the colorbox trigger has hidden the links... but hasn't removed them :(

Comment: If the problem is the Accessibility errors maybe you should alter the js codes and provide a title attribute to prev/next links instead of removing them at all. Or add this attribute with custom js outside colorbox module.